# libc : Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x7129621350 in tid 29032 (AudioRecord)

Tags: android, pjsip

I'm developing a voip app using PJSIP 2.8. Recently I've moved to aab package approach and providing support for 64 bit device so when my device run on 64 bit device "arm64-v8a" it crashed during the call with this error

```
libc    : Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x7129621350 in tid 29032 (AudioRecord)
```

It worked fine if i prepare a apk and remove ndk filter from gradle.

Any help is much appreciated.